# Application-transparent encryption among cloud-deployed servers

Tags: linux, security, virtual-machines, encryption, cloud

I'm a software engineer and not necessarily an ops guy aside from having done a developer's share of dealing with deployment issues.

The individual components of the web app I'm working on will be distributed over distinct cloud-based VMs. What's the best or at least a good practice to go about encrypting communication among e.g. node.js-based http-services and the database - each living in their own instances?

I was thinking of `SSH`-tunnels between the boxes ... What do you serverfault pros say?

Answer (score 2):

This seems perilously close to a shopping question, which are prohibited on SF (and other SE sites, apparently) by the FAQ.  You also fail to mention what OS will be running on the cloud servers; but I'll go ahead and assume it's Linux.

That said, my first preference would be for IPSec, since it's built into Linux, it's incredibly robust, and well-integrated at the network level (so you don't have to mess with routing tables).  There won't be any issues about authentication, since it's all done with pre-shared keys or certificates.  It integrates well with `iptables` firewalls.  It recovers well after extended network outages.  It comes up automatically at boot time via standard `/etc/rcN.d` scripts.  With IPSec tunnels in place, applications need only throw packets at IP addresses; the encryption all happens **way** down the stack from there.

Failing that, OpenVPN.  It's more complex than IPSec, but shares many of the same advantages.

Failing that, ssh tunnels if you must - but you'll be forever running around putting them back once network outages have made them fall over.  I'd rather have (yet more) root canal work than do this with ssh tunnels.

Comment: Whatever a "shopping question" is supposed to be ... err ... I wasn't intending on posting one o_0
... and yes, you are assuming right: the servers/VMs will be running Linux. Thanks for the pointers to IPSec and OpenVPN. They are something I'll be looking into.

Comment: Check the FAQ (it's linked from the top of every SF page), and http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/ .  Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

[stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/index.html) might be an interesting option too. If you have several VMs (not just two), setting a VPN for them and routing all traffic among the nodes through it could be also sensible to some degree - it would protect "everything forever" - if you add another interconnect, it will by encrypted by default without any need to set up additional `ssh`/`stunnel` forwardings. Enforcing IPSec might be another option.